# React-Native with react-navigation navigate is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

react-navigation, navigation.navigate is not working in my component and does not show any error.

here is my navigator shopNavigation component:

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {Platform} from 'react-native';

import ProducOverviewScreen from '../screens/shop/ProductOverviewScreen';
import ProductDetailScreen from '../screens/shop/ProductDetailScreen';

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

const ProductNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ProductOverview: ProducOverviewScreen,
    ProductDetail: ProductDetailScreen
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primary: '',
      },
      headerTinColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primary,
    },
  },
);

export default createAppContainer(ProductNavigator);
```

and this is the component i want to do the navigate function
ProductOverview

```
import React from 'react';
import {FlatList, Text} from 'react-native';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import ProductItem from '../../components/shop/ProductItem';
import { withNavigation, navigate } from 'react-navigation';


const ProductOverviewScreen = (props) => {
  const products = useSelector(state => state.products.availableProducts);
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={products}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      renderItem={itemData => (
        <ProductItem
          image={itemData.item.imageUrl}
          title={itemData.item.title}
          price={itemData.item.price}
          onViewDetail={()=> {
           props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetail')
        }}
          onAddToCart={() => {}}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};

ProductOverviewScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'All Products',
  color: 'white',
  headerTitleStyle: {
    color: 'white',
  },
};

export default ProductOverviewScreen;
```

the doc of react-navigation is not telling me much.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post `ProductItem` as well.

Comment: ah yes the solution was there it was on view details not Detail Thanks